Missing a required argument: 'dec_input' in Transformer Model
I am busy with a forecasting model, and have turned to Transformers to see if they will be able to perform better than other sequence models.
I keep getting the error:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[169], line 23
      5 transformer = Transformer(
      6     num_layers=4,
      7     d_model=128,
   (...)
     13     rate=0.1
     14 )
     16 transformer.compile(
     17     optimizer=optimizer,
     18     loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
     19     metrics=["mae"]
     20 )
---> 23 history = transformer.fit(
     24     [train_enc_input, train_dec_input],  # Tuple of encoder and decoder inputs
     25     y=train_y,  # Target sequence (desired output)
     26     validation_data=([val_enc_input, val_dec_input], val_y),  # Validation data
     27     batch_size=64,  # Batch size for training
     28     epochs=10  # Number of epochs
     29 )

File Forecast-Modeling\Environments\internal_forecasts\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py:122, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    119     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    120     # To get the full stack trace, call:
...
   3128 else:
   3129     # We have a positional argument to process
   3130     try:

TypeError: missing a required argument: 'dec_input'

I have set up the entire Transformer like this:

Setting up the sequences which are fed into the model

import numpy as np

def create_sequences_with_decoder(input_data, target_data, sequence_length, forecast_horizon, num_features):
    """
    Creates sequences for a transformer-based model with encoder and decoder inputs.
    
    Args:
    - input_data (pd.DataFrame): Input features for the encoder.
    - target_data (pd.DataFrame or pd.Series): Target variable for the decoder.
    - sequence_length (int): Number of past time steps for the encoder.
    - forecast_horizon (int): Number of future time steps for the decoder.
    - num_features (int): Number of features in the target variable.

    Returns:
    - enc_input (np.ndarray): Encoder input, shape (num_samples, sequence_length, num_features).
    - dec_input (np.ndarray): Decoder input, shape (num_samples, forecast_horizon, num_features).
    - y (np.ndarray): Target sequence, shape (num_samples, forecast_horizon).
    """
    enc_input, dec_input, y = [], [], []
    
    for i in range(len(input_data) - sequence_length - forecast_horizon + 1):
        # Extract encoder input: past sequence
        past_sequence = input_data[i:(i + sequence_length)].to_numpy()
        enc_input.append(past_sequence)
        
        # Extract target sequence
        target_seq = target_data[i + sequence_length:(i + sequence_length + forecast_horizon)].to_numpy()
        
        # Ensure target_seq is 2D (forecast_horizon, num_features)
        if target_seq.ndim == 1:
            target_seq = target_seq[:, np.newaxis]
        
        # Create decoder input by adding a start token
        start_token = np.zeros((1, target_seq.shape[1]))  # Shape (1, num_features)
        shifted_sequence = np.vstack((start_token, target_seq[:-1]))  # Shape (forecast_horizon, num_features)
        dec_input.append(shifted_sequence)
        
        # Add the target sequence
        y.append(target_seq)
    
    # Convert lists to numpy arrays
    enc_input = np.array(enc_input)  # Shape (num_samples, sequence_length, num_features)
    dec_input = np.array(dec_input)  # Shape (num_samples, forecast_horizon, num_features)
    y = np.array(y)  # Shape (num_samples, forecast_horizon, num_features)
    y = y.squeeze(-1)
    # # Reshape y to (num_samples, forecast_horizon) if num_features == 1
    # if num_features == 1:
    #     y = y.squeeze(-1)
    
    return enc_input, dec_input, y


# Define parameters
sequence_length = 8  # Number of past time steps for encoder input
forecast_horizon = 6  # Number of future time steps for decoder and target
num_features = train_y.shape[-1]  # This is the number of features in train_y

# Create sequences
train_enc_input, train_dec_input, train_y = create_sequences_with_decoder(
    pd.DataFrame(turbine_training_df_normalized), 
    turbine_training_y, 
    sequence_length, 
    forecast_horizon,
    num_features
)

The shapes are as follows:
Train encoder input shape: (472725, 8, 9)
Train decoder input shape: (472725, 6, 1)
Train target shape: (472725, 6)

The Rest of the model construction is as follows:

"""
Model Architecture
"""

# Parameters for the model
d_model = 64  # Embedding dimension
num_heads = 4  # Number of attention heads
num_encoder_layers = 3  # Number of encoder layers
num_decoder_layers = 3  # Number of decoder layers
dff = 256  # Feed-forward network dimension
dropout_rate = 0.1  # Dropout rate

# Input shapes
input_length = 8  # Number of past steps to look back
forecast_horizon = 6  # Steps ahead to predict
num_features = turbine_training_df_normalized.shape[1]  # Number of input features (e.g., wind speed)

# Define the Input layers
encoder_input = Input(shape=(input_length, num_features), name="encoder_input")
decoder_input = Input(shape=(forecast_horizon, num_features), name="decoder_input")

"""
Positional encoding
"""

def positional_encoding(position, d_model):
    angle_rads = np.arange(position)[:, np.newaxis] / np.power(10000, (2 * (np.arange(d_model) // 2)) / np.float32(d_model))
    angle_rads[:, 0::2] = np.sin(angle_rads[:, 0::2])  # apply sine to even indices in the dimension
    angle_rads[:, 1::2] = np.cos(angle_rads[:, 1::2])  # apply cosine to odd indices
    return tf.constant(angle_rads, dtype=tf.float32)

# Add positional encoding to encoder and decoder inputs
encoder_pos_encoding = positional_encoding(input_length, d_model)
decoder_pos_encoding = positional_encoding(forecast_horizon, d_model)


def create_look_ahead_mask(size):
    """Creates a look-ahead mask for the decoder."""
    mask = tf.linalg.band_part(tf.ones((size, size)), -1, 0)  # Lower triangular matrix
    return mask

def add_positional_encoding(input, pos_encoding):
    return input + pos_encoding[: tf.shape(input)[1], :]

# Add positional encodings to embeddings
encoder_input_with_pos = add_positional_encoding(encoder_input, encoder_pos_encoding)
decoder_input_with_pos = add_positional_encoding(decoder_input, decoder_pos_encoding)

"""
Multihead layers
"""

class MultiHeadSelfAttention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, d_model, num_heads):
        super(MultiHeadSelfAttention, self).__init__()
        self.num_heads = num_heads
        self.d_model = d_model
        assert d_model % self.num_heads == 0
        self.depth = d_model // self.num_heads

        self.wq = tf.keras.layers.Dense(d_model)
        self.wk = tf.keras.layers.Dense(d_model)
        self.wv = tf.keras.layers.Dense(d_model)
        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(d_model)

    def split_heads(self, x, batch_size):
        x = tf.reshape(x, (batch_size, -1, self.num_heads, self.depth))
        return tf.transpose(x, perm=[0, 2, 1, 3])

    def call(self, v, k, q, mask):
        batch_size = tf.shape(q)[0]
        q = self.wq(q)
        k = self.wk(k)
        v = self.wv(v)

        q = self.split_heads(q, batch_size)
        k = self.split_heads(k, batch_size)
        v = self.split_heads(v, batch_size)

        scaled_attention, _ = scaled_dot_product_attention(q, k, v, mask)
        scaled_attention = tf.transpose(scaled_attention, perm=[0, 2, 1, 3])
        concat_attention = tf.reshape(scaled_attention, (batch_size, -1, self.d_model))

        output = self.dense(concat_attention)
        return output

"""Transformer Layers (Encoder/Decoder)"""

def scaled_dot_product_attention(q, k, v, mask=None):

    matmul_qk = tf.matmul(q, k, transpose_b=True)
    dk = tf.cast(tf.shape(k)[-1], tf.float32)
    scaled_attention_logits = matmul_qk / tf.math.sqrt(dk)

    if mask is not None:
        scaled_attention_logits += (mask * -1e9)

    attention_weights = tf.nn.softmax(scaled_attention_logits, axis=-1)
    output = tf.matmul(attention_weights, v)
    return output, attention_weights


class TransformerEncoderLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, d_model, num_heads, dff, rate=0.1):
        super(TransformerEncoderLayer, self).__init__()
        self.mha = MultiHeadSelfAttention(d_model, num_heads)
        self.ffn = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(dff, activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(d_model)
        ])
        self.layernorm1 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.layernorm2 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.dropout1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate)
        self.dropout2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate)

    def call(self, x, training, mask):
        attn_output, _ = self.mha(x, x, x, mask)
        attn_output = self.dropout1(attn_output, training=training)
        out1 = self.layernorm1(x + attn_output)

        ffn_output = self.ffn(out1)
        ffn_output = self.dropout2(ffn_output, training=training)
        out2 = self.layernorm2(out1 + ffn_output)
        return out2

# Decoder layer

class TransformerDecoderLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, d_model, num_heads, dff, rate=0.1):
        super(TransformerDecoderLayer, self).__init__()
        self.mha1 = MultiHeadSelfAttention(d_model, num_heads)
        self.mha2 = MultiHeadSelfAttention(d_model, num_heads)
        
        self.ffn = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(dff, activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(d_model)
        ])
        
        self.layernorm1 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.layernorm2 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.layernorm3 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)

        self.dropout1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate)
        self.dropout2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate)
        self.dropout3 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate)

    def call(self, x, enc_output, training, look_ahead_mask, padding_mask):
        attn1, _ = self.mha1(x, x, x, look_ahead_mask)
        attn1 = self.dropout1(attn1, training=training)
        out1 = self.layernorm1(attn1 + x)

        attn2, _ = self.mha2(enc_output, enc_output, out1, padding_mask)
        attn2 = self.dropout2(attn2, training=training)
        out2 = self.layernorm2(attn2 + out1)

        ffn_output = self.ffn(out2)
        ffn_output = self.dropout3(ffn_output, training=training)
        out3 = self.layernorm3(ffn_output + out2)
        return out3

# Stack Encoder and Decoder Layers

class TransformerEncoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_layers, d_model, num_heads, dff, input_vocab_size, maximum_position_encoding, rate=0.1):
        super(TransformerEncoder, self).__init__()
        self.d_model = d_model
        self.num_layers = num_layers

        self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Dense(d_model)
        self.pos_encoding = positional_encoding(maximum_position_encoding, self.d_model)
        
        self.enc_layers = [TransformerEncoderLayer(d_model, num_heads, dff, rate) for _ in range(num_layers)]
        self.dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate)

    def call(self, x, training, mask):
        x = self.embedding(x)
        x += self.pos_encoding[:, :tf.shape(x)[1], :]
        x = self.dropout(x, training=training)

        for i in range(self.num_layers):
            x = self.enc_layers[i](x, training, mask)

        return x

class TransformerDecoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_layers, d_model, num_heads, dff, target_vocab_size, maximum_position_encoding, rate=0.1):
        super(TransformerDecoder, self).__init__()
        self.d_model = d_model
        self.num_layers = num_layers

        self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Dense(d_model)
        self.pos_encoding = positional_encoding(maximum_position_encoding, self.d_model)

        self.dec_layers = [TransformerDecoderLayer(d_model, num_heads, dff, rate) for _ in range(num_layers)]
        self.dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate)

    def call(self, x, enc_output, training, look_ahead_mask, padding_mask):
        x = self.embedding(x)
        x += self.pos_encoding[:, :tf.shape(x)[1], :]
        x = self.dropout(x, training=training)

        attention_weights = {}
        for i, dec_layer in enumerate(self.dec_layers):
            x, block1, block2 = dec_layer(x, enc_output, training, look_ahead_mask, padding_mask)
            attention_weights[f"decoder_layer{i+1}_block1"] = block1
            attention_weights[f"decoder_layer{i+1}_block2"] = block2

        return x, attention_weights


Now where I think the issue is happening is here, in the Transformer assembly
class Transformer(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, num_layers, d_model, num_heads, dff, input_dim, target_dim,
                 maximum_position_encoding, rate=0.1):
        super(Transformer, self).__init__()

        self.encoder = TransformerEncoder(num_layers, d_model, num_heads, dff, input_dim, maximum_position_encoding, rate)
        self.decoder = TransformerDecoder(num_layers, d_model, num_heads, dff, target_dim, maximum_position_encoding, rate)

        # Final dense layer to output predictions
        self.final_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(target_dim)

    def call(self, enc_input, dec_input, training, 
             enc_padding_mask=None, look_ahead_mask=None, dec_padding_mask=None):
        # Encoding input sequence
        enc_output = self.encoder(enc_input, training, enc_padding_mask)

        # Create look-ahead mask dynamically during training
        if look_ahead_mask is None:
            look_ahead_mask = create_look_ahead_mask(tf.shape(dec_input)[1])

        # Decoding forecasted sequence
        dec_output, attention_weights = self.decoder(
            dec_input, enc_output, training, look_ahead_mask, dec_padding_mask)

        # Mapping decoder output to target dimension for forecasts
        final_output = self.final_layer(dec_output)

        return final_output, attention_weights

Here is the compiling
"""
Compile the model
"""
# Define and compile the transformer
transformer = Transformer(
    num_layers=4,
    d_model=128,
    num_heads=4,
    dff=256,
    input_dim=train_enc_input.shape[-1],
    target_dim=train_y.shape[-1],
    maximum_position_encoding=max(input_length, forecast_horizon),
    rate=0.1
)

transformer.compile(
    optimizer=optimizer,
    loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
    metrics=["mae"]
)


history = transformer.fit(
    x=[train_enc_input, train_dec_input],  # Tuple of encoder and decoder inputs
    y=train_y,  # Target sequence (desired output)
    validation_data=([val_enc_input, val_dec_input], val_y),  # Validation data
    batch_size=64,  # Batch size for training
    epochs=10  # Number of epochs
)

I have tried a number of different approaches, but just can't seem to work out what the issue is.
